# Create HTTP route from static template in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a route template defined in a variable like this:

```
public const string DetailsListPage = BasePage + "/{Caption}/{Source}/{Id}";
```

In my Blazor app, I use it like this in Blazor pages:

```
@attribute [Route(Routes.ImportVariants.DetailsListPage)]
```

However, I can't find a way to use this route template to navigate to it.

```
string.Format(Routes.ImportVariants.DetailsListPage, context.Caption, context.Source, context.Id); // does not work
NavigationManager.NavigateTo(Routes.ImportVariants.DetailsListPage, context.Caption, context.Source, context.Id); // does not work
```

Is there a way to somehow generate a URL using this template?

Comment: What is `BasePage`?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis also a static string.

Comment: Is Kurt's answer good?  Don't want to think bout this if you already have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined a route path in a constant:

```
public const string DetailsListPage = BasePage + "/{Caption}/{Source}/{Id}";
```

and you are using it to define a route in a razor page:

```
@attribute [Route(Routes.ImportVariants.DetailsListPage)]
```

and you want to use it to navigate to a route like:

```
var url = "/My-Base-Page/Some-Caption/Some-Source/123";
NavigationManager.NavigateTo(url);
```

then you need to work out how to replace the route placeholders with variable values at the point that you are generating the target url.

One option is to use simple string replacement:

```
var caption = "My-Caption";
var source = "My-Source";
var id = 123;

var urlTemplate = Routes.ImportVariants.DetailsListPage;
// Replace each parameter placeholder one-by-one here
var url = urlTemplate
  .Replace("{Caption}", caption)
  .Replace("{Source}", source
  .Replace("{Id}", id.ToString());

NavigationManager.NavigateTo(url);
```

Remember that `String.Replace(str, str)` is case-sensitive by default.

**String.Format**

String format would expect something like:

`string.Format(BasePage + "/{0}/{1}/{2}", caption, source, id)`

which is obviously different from the Blazor route template format.

In general you should try to keep these concerns separate - route definitions and string formatting are 2 separate concerns (even though you are doing both to enable navigation in your app).